# Substituting text by checking range of int

Tags: python, xml, string, text, beautifulsoup

I have a xml-like line that notes the year range of some text, e.g. the default is to set `no` attribute for all year range values as such:

```
textf = """<textf no="1958-1960" no="1961-1963" no="1964-1966" no="1967-1969" no="1970-1972" no="1973-1975" no="1976-1978" no="1979-1981" no="1982-1984" no="1985-1987" no="1988-1990" no="1991-1993" no="1994-1996" no="1997-1999" no="2000-2002" no="2003-2005" no="2006-2008" no="2009-2011" no="2012-2014">Some text</textf>"""
```

I understand that the attribute should have been the years and the value should have been a boolean `true/false` but this standard is set by someone else and I'm suppose to use it.

So let's say the `Some text` is from **1963**, I am suppose to change the `no` to a `yes` for which the value is `"1961-1963"`, i.e. the above text would become:

```
"""<textf no="1958-1960" yes="1961-1963" no="1964-1966" no="1967-1969" no="1970-1972" no="1973-1975" no="1976-1978" no="1979-1981" no="1982-1984" no="1985-1987" no="1988-1990" no="1991-1993" no="1994-1996" no="1997-1999" no="2000-2002" no="2003-2005" no="2006-2008" no="2009-2011" no="2012-2014">Some text</textf>"""
```

I've been doing it by replacing the ranges in integer and checking through all the year ranges one by one as such:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
textf = """<textf no="1958-1960" no="1961-1963" no="1964-1966" no="1967-1969" no="1970-1972" no="1973-1975" no="1976-1978" no="1979-1981" no="1982-1984" no="1985-1987" no="1988-1990" no="1991-1993" no="1994-1996" no="1997-1999" no="2000-2002" no="2003-2005" no="2006-2008" no="2009-2011" no="2012-2014">"""
textf_range =  [map(int, j.split('-')) for i,j in BeautifulSoup(textf).find('textf').attrs]
year = 1961
year_range_yes = ['yes="'+str(i)+'-'+str(j)+'"' for i,j in textf_range if year in range(i,j)][0]
year_range_no = year_range_yes.replace('yes=', 'no=')
tagged_textf = textf.replace(year_range_no, year_range_yes)
print tagged_textf
```

[out]:

```
"""<textf no="1958-1960" yes="1961-1963" no="1964-1966" no="1967-1969" no="1970-1972" no="1973-1975" no="1976-1978" no="1979-1981" no="1982-1984" no="1985-1987" no="1988-1990" no="1991-1993" no="1994-1996" no="1997-1999" no="2000-2002" no="2003-2005" no="2006-2008" no="2009-2011" no="2012-2014">Some text</textf>"""
```

**Is there a simpler way of doing this? A more pythonic way perhaps and less convoluted, less verbose way.** Hopefully a way without BeautifulSoup would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using regular expression:

```
>>> import re
>>>
>>> def yes_if_include(m, y):
...     y1, y2 = map(int, m.group(1, 2))
...     if y1 <= y <= y2:
...         return 'yes' + m.group()[2:]
...     return m.group()
...
>>> textf = '<textf no="1958-1960" no="1961-1963" no="1964-1966">Some text</textf>'
>>> re.sub(r'no="(\d+)-(\d+)"', lambda m: yes_if_include(m, 1963), textf)
'<textf no="1958-1960" yes="1961-1963" no="1964-1966">Some text</textf>'
```